# Learning decryption -- what type of encryption is this?

Tags: encryption, cryptography

Edit: The code snippet contains GUID's and was never encrypted in the first place. Also, sorry for being stupid.

I am trying to figure out how to decrypt one line of code and has the following pattern:

```
c1fb1fc0-df8e-46ff-9f54-20d990f7bc0f

ce0d48e7-fb20-46eb-b9c9-4a05775031b3

8bfb481b-be0d-4079-9b12-7b2dd491ed3b

ae267429-f23a-4d0c-a00f-54e44416a016

3c3eff29-fc43-4da2-8a54-fbd9b5aa7874

2dc7108d-a4dd-4530-ac7d-deb175011dd0
```

Always one line with an 8-4-4-4-12 pattern of case-sensitive alpha numeric values. What cipher is used to encrypt this output?

I've been staring at this problem for far too long and a fresh pair of eyes would help.

Comment: Just because you can't understand a bunch of data doesn't mean it is encrypted.

Comment: See [GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Format) - note that the `8-4-4-4-12` pattern you spotted is stated exactly on that link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These look like GUIDs and they aren't decryptable to anything.

Comment: Thank you, not the first time I've felt stupid on this site and it probably won't be the last.